# Difference between jobs and maintenance plan in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between jobs and maintenance plan in sql server?

I am confused about where I should use job and where maintenance plan.

Answer (score 8):

Jobs are user defined scheduled tasks (could be stored procedures, emails and more).

[Maintenance plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx) are used to optimize the database.

From MSDN:

> Maintenance plans create a workflow of the tasks required to make sure that your database is optimized, is regularly backed up, and is free of inconsistencies.

A maintenance plan may use jobs as part of the workflow.

A job may be part of a maintenance plan.

Answer (score 0):

A Maintenance plan is a GUI that can create one or more SQL Jobs to maintain one or more Databases on your Server.

If you want to perform scheduled Database maintenance then use a Maintenance Plan.  If you want to perform some kind of custom action e.g Clearing a sessions table then create your own Job.

In most cases there is no need to create your own Maintenance Jobs and the GUI does a good job.